# Can't connect to a remote server even though the config seems correct

Tags: redis

My Redis instance is running at 192.168.1.101.

Redis version is 4.0.1

I want to to be able to connect this Redis instance from 192.168.1.103, but I can't.

I type `redis-cli -h 192.168.1.101 -p 6379 -a myredisPasswordisHere` while I'm at 192.168.1.103

It returns

```
Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.1.101:6379: Connection refused
Could not connect to Redis at 192.168.1.101:6379: Connection refused
```

Here's the related part of the Redis.conf, it's located in `/usr/local/etc/redis.conf`. I've installed it via Homebrew.

TL;DR

```
protected-mode yes
bind 192.168.1.100 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.102 192.168.1.103 192.168.1.104
requirepass myredisPasswordisHere
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you try `bind 0.0.0.0` ?

Comment: It works, but doesn't this make my Redis instance available everybody on the internet to connect? I only want to allow certain hosts.

Comment: The parameter to `bind` is not a list of the host IP addresses that can connect. Rather, it is the IP address of the **interface on the local machine** on which Redis should listen. Surely, as you are using `192.168.x.x` addresses, you are behind a firewall/router so your network should be invisible to the outside world and you can use `bind 0.0.0.0` which means Redis should *"listen on all interfaces"*.

Comment: You'll need to protect that open instance with a firewall, e.g. iptables

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm going to use iptables for this. If one of you write an answer, I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @ItamarHaber If one of you write an answer, I'm going to accept it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell If one of you write an answer, I'm going to accept it.

Comment: The credit belongs to @SudheeshSinganamalla imo

Comment: Agreed, go for it Sudheesh.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark and Itamar. I've posted an answer with credits to both of you for chiming in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the `redis` service to be available for other remote hosts to query it, You need to bind it publicly to serve using `bind 0.0.0.0`

As the other comments from @Itamar and @Mark clearly mention, bind isn't the list of IP addresses that can connect but rather the interface on the local machine. Once the service is publicly available and running with `0.0.0.0` for your requirement of only allowing specific hosts, you need some kind of a firewall with a whitelist of IP addresses that can access this host which you can achieve with `iptables`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and please accept my apologies since I've totally ignored your comment and did not investigate the subject in detail.